# what is the correct runlevel for "Stop" in ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, runlevel

I am trying to make a script to gracefully shutdown some application servers, I put the scripts in /etc/rc0.d but when I stop the ec2 instance on amazon, it won't call my script.

what is the correct runlevel for "stop" in ec2?

Comment: What distro are you running?

Comment: Amazon Linux or Redhat